# Does LastActivityDate for a question from Posts.xml consider answers, comments, votes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump, last-activity

From some answers regarding LastActivityDate, I know that LastActivityDate of a question considers:

a) Posting a question,

b) Answering a question,

c) Edits to either question or answer(s)

I want to know if LastActivityDate of a question from Posts.xml considers the following scenarios:

a) Comment on a question,

b) Comment on any answer of a question,

c) Vote (upvote/downvote) to a question,

d) Vote (upvote/downvote) to any answer of a question,

e) Upvote to any comment on a question or any answer of a question?

Comment: Thank you. Indeed this question is a duplicate. I didn't know the term **bumped**.